# Android OnTouchListener receives 2 events on one click

Tags: android

Hello I have a couple of EditText widgets that I want to change the behaviour of depending on user preferences. The user should be able to change the EditText views so a popup comes forth with a number of alternatives. When the user want to use a list for input I will set an onTouchListener instead.

It is working quite well except that the onTouchListener ***receives two events when I click once*** so two popupdialogs appear. This is the OnTouchListener:

```
 private OnTouchListener mInputListOnTouckListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
 {
        EditText et;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View ve, MotionEvent me)
        {   
            final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
            et = (EditText)ve;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("Pick a number");

            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {   
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item ) 
                {
                    et.setText(items[item]);
                    return;
                }
            });

            builder.create().show();
            return true;
        }
 };
```

PS: Yes I want to return true because it prevents the keyboard from showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting an ACTION_DOWN event when you touch the screen, and an ACTION_UP event when you release it. Use the [getAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction%28%29) method on the MotionEvent to determine which event you're getting, and do your stuff only on ACTION_UP for example.